# Valores booleanos para tuplas SQL en mySQL-workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, backend

Estoy trabajando de una base de datos para un empresa que quiere montar una pagina web tipo mercadolibre, las regla de negocio dicen que que el producto que vende cada usuario tiene que tener una disponibilidad de: **disponible** y **no disponible** estaba pensando en usar valores booleanos pero veo que en mysql-workbench no se puede ¿como agrego esta funcionalidad?

Comment: Puedes hacer esa columna de tipo `int` y asignar los valores `0` y `1` dependiendo de la disponibilidad del producto.

Comment: Usa tinyint y con eso lo tienes, en todo caso hablas del MySQL server, el otro es solo un ide para manipular al primero que menciono

Comment: @itsnesky considero innecesario usar `int`, cuando el OP solo desea guardar dos estados y para eso con tinyint alcanza